# Injectable ApplicationConfig service

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi

I want a service I can inject - or in my example get with `GetService` - that contains settings from my `appsettings.json` file.

The `appsettings.json` fragment looks like this:

```
  "ExternalInterfaces": [
      {
        "Name": "name1",
        "BaseUrl": "https://www.baseurl1.svc"
      },
      {
        "Name": "name2",
        "BaseUrl": "https://www.baseurl2.svc"
      }
    ]
```

To do this I have the following interfaces:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Infrastructure.Settings
{
    public interface IExternalInterfaceSettingsCollection
    {
        IReadOnlyCollection<IExternalInterfaceSettings> Settings { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace Infrastructure.Settings
{
    public interface IExternalInterfaceSettings
    {
        string Name { get; set; }
        string BaseUrl { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and the following corresponding classes:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Infrastructure.Settings
{
    public class ExternalInterfaceSettingsCollection : IExternalInterfaceSettingsCollection
    {
        public IReadOnlyCollection<IExternalInterfaceSettings> Settings { get; set; }
    }
}
namespace Infrastructure.Settings
{
    public class ExternalInterfaceSettings : IExternalInterfaceSettings
    {
        const string DefaultName = "newExternalInterface";
        const string DefaultBaseUrl = "";

        public string Name { get; set; } = DefaultName;
        public string BaseUrl { get; set; } = DefaultBaseUrl;
    }
}
```

And in my `Startup.cs` I have this (definitely gets called with no exceptions):

```
services.Configure<IExternalInterfaceSettingsCollection>(settings => _configuration.GetSection("ExternalInterfaces").Bind(settings));
```

and this is then consumed as follows:

```
var externalInterfaceConfiguration = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<ExternalInterfaceSettingsCollection>();
var Setting1BaseUrl = externalInterfaceConfiguration.Settings
    .SingleOrDefault(s => s.Name == "name1")?.BaseUrl;
```

However, in the last 3 lines, `externalInterfaceConfiguration` is always null.

I'm clearly missing something, but I can't see what. Any clues?

Comment: Don't kwno if it helps

Startup: services.AddOptions().Configure<QiwiSettings>(_configuration.GetSection("QiwiSettings"));

Injection to constructor:

public Smth(IOptions<QiwiSettings> options)
{
    var test = options.Value.MySetting;
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've registered `IExternalInterfaceSettings`, but you're attempting to retrieve `ExternalInterfaceSettings`. There's no such service in the collection, so the result is null (since you used `GetService<T>`). If you had used `GetRequiredService<T>` then an exception would have been thrown telling you as much.

Then, the options pattern is not meant to bind to interfaces. The whole idea is that you're binding to a POCO that represents a specific set of settings. If you want to use an interface, I suppose that's your prerogative, but it's not going to be applicable to the options configuration. In other words, you need the following instead:

```
services.Configure<ExternalInterfaceSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("ExternalInterfaces"));
```

*(Note, the action overload with `Bind` is superfluous. You can just pass the config section directly.)*

With that, you'll be able to request something like `IOptions<ExternalInterfaceSettings>`, but you still cannot get `ExternalInterfaceSettings` directly from the service collection. If you want *that* functionality, you'll need to add an additional service registration (which can utilize an interface, this time):

```
services.AddScoped<IExternalInterfaceSettings, ExternalInterfaceSettings>(p =>
    p.GetRequiredService<IOptions<ExternalInterfaceSettings>>().Value);
```

Comment: I think you are right. Leaving the office now but I'll try this tomorrow.